# Generalization of scalar product for vectors in n-dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Let $x$ and $y$ be two vectors and $A$ the angle between them. Then we have the scalar product $$x\cdot y = \|x\|\|y\| \cos A$$

Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be three vectors; $A$ angle between $x$ and $y$; $B$ angle between $x$ and $z$; and $C$ angle between $y$ and $z$.
What is the value of the scalar product for the three vectors?
Generalization: What is the value of the scalar product for $N$ vectors in $n$-dimensional space?

In 2-dimensional space we define a symmetric bilinear form for scalar product.
In n-dimensional space can we define a symmetric multilinear form for N vectors?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: I think this reference might help you :[Vectors in n-dimensional Space The Cauchy-Schwarz and Triangle Inequalities](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/241.spring14/nspace.pdf) It mentions: The algebraic definitions of vector addition, multiplication by scalar, and the dot product, extend to n-dimensional space in the obvious way. (The geometric interpretations of these operations (e.g., dot product formula in terms of angles and
magnitudes) make only sense in $R_2$ and $R_3$ and do not extend to n-dimensional spaces. Also, the cross product, as defined in class, makes only sense in $R_3$.)

Comment: It's a good idea! Can we just do it the obvious way -- $(a, b) \cdot (c, d) \cdot (e, f) = ace + bdf$? Would you want to value to be related to *all* of the angles $A, B, C$? i.e. $x \cdot y \cdot z = ||x||||y||||z||\cos(A)\cos(B)\cos(C)$ or something similar?

Comment: You can certainly think of symmetric $k$-linear forms as generalizations of the dot product, but they don't necessarily have any nice geometric interpretation in terms of lengths and angles the way that the dot product does.  For instance, the "obvious" generalization of the dot product given by $T(a,b,c) = \sum_i a_ib_ic_i$ is *coordinate-dependent* (and thus not very useful).

Comment: @Mufasa: What your source says is true, but the OP's question is about a function that would take in $n$ vectors and give a scalar, which I don't think is mentioned there. (Also, clarifying more for myself than anyone else, it's still true that $x \cdot y = ||x||||y||\cos(\theta)$ when $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for $n > 3$, the author's point is just that it's hard for humans to think about $4$-dimensional angles).

Comment: @Bye_World: Wow! Why is it coordinate-dependent for $n = 2$ but not $n \ge 3$?

Comment: looks like the same question was asked here (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545870/generalized-scalar-product-based-on-multilinear-form?rq=1), but I haven't understood the answer yet.

Comment: @EliRose "Why?" is not usually a question I know how to answer in math.  But it's easy to *show* that the product $\sum_i a_ib_i$ is invariant under orthogonal (length-preserving) transformations.  Try to prove for yourself that if $R$ is any orthogonal transformation then $\sum_i (Ra)_i(Rb)_i = \sum_i a_ib_i$.  Now let's try this for the generalization $T$ I define above.  In fact, we don't need to try to prove it for all orthogonal transformations -- let's just consider one very simple transform: $v\mapsto -v$.  Then $T(-a,-b,-c) = \sum_i (-a_i)(-b_i)(-c_i) = -\sum_i a_ib_ic_i \ne T(a,b,c)$.

Comment: The scalar product make sens in 2 and 3-dimensional space.The idea to extend it to n-dimensional space. From n vectors we provide a scalar .

Comment: 3 vectors  U, V, W ; absolute values   a, b, c ;  α ,β ,γ angles between it .
-  scalar product   {U.V.W} = abc cos Ω        Ω  is the solid angle
 cross product [U, V, W] = abc sin Ω
                       Generalization 
Cos Ωn = 1 – (det Gram)/ (1+cos α1)(1+cos α2)......(1+cos αn)
Sin Ωn = sqrt(det Gram)*(1+cos α1 +cos α2…+cosαn)/ (1+cos α1)(1+cos α2)... ......(1+cos αn)
 dot product 
Dn=a1*a2*.......an* cos Ωn 
 cross product 
Cn = a1*a2*…….an* sin Ωn
 [a1,a2,….an]  anti-symmetric multilinear form
{a1.a2.…….an} symmetric multilinear form

Comment: @Bye_World: Thanks, that's a really good illustration!

Comment: I didn't understand the comments… OP is asking about extension to N-dimensional vectors, not extension to a three argument operator. What am I missing? How is the question mentioned by @EliRose pertinent at all?

Answer (score 1):

The notion of scalar product is defined for 2 vectors, not only for 2-dimensional spaces but for n-dimensional spaces as well, as is the corresponding (for the geometric interpretation) notion of the angle, which also only takes two vectors.

A generelisation in linear algebra is a scalar product that is defined as a bilinear, symmetric (as you said) and positive definite (i.e. $\left<v,v\right>>0 $ for $v\neq0$) map $V\times V \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ where $\mathbb{K}$ is either $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ and $V$ is a vector space.

Now, independent of the dimension of your space you can define multilinear maps which are a generalisation of bilinear maps and can also have properties like symmetry, but scalar product is a term that refers to maps that takes 2 arguments in all occasions I've encountered so far.

Comment: What is a N-dimensional angle? How do we justify the 'projection' intuition to higher dimensional spaces? Trigonometry helps me only in 2D…